# appium test fails when trying to zoom map

Tags: java, ios, appium, appium-ios, xcuitest

I run test with Appium 1.7.2 in iOS. I need to zoom on the map. I get map element into theMap variable and try to zoom by different ways, however all of them fails:

Method 1:

```
TouchAction action1 = new TouchAction(driver).press(100,100).moveTo(0,-50).release();
        TouchAction acction2 = new TouchAction(driver).press(100,200).moveTo(0,50).release();
        MultiTouchAction mta = new MultiTouchAction(driver);
        mta.add(action1).add(acction2);
        mta.perform();
```

This crash on perform() method. If I remove one of the actions and stay

```
mta.add(action1);
        mta.perform();
```

Or

```
mta.add(action2);
        mta.perform();
```

There is no problem and action performed.

Appium server get 501 error from WDA.

Method 2:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(theMap);
        action.doubleClick(theMap);
        action.perform();
```

Crash on perform() as well.

In both cases I get InvocationTargetException. Any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: what version of appium-java-client are you using?

Comment: Have you tried either `driver.zoom(theMap);` or the corresponding zoom with the x and y position parameters?  You might need to tap the element first, I've not tried this.

Answer (score 0):

I found alternative way to zoom.

```
public void zoom(RemoteWebElement element){
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("scale", 10);
    params.put("velocity", 2);
    params.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
    js.executeScript("mobile: pinch", params);
}
```

where element is parent element contains map and all the items on it.